# Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf`

Tags: react-native, npm-install

absolute beginner in react native here,

I'm trying to follow the react native tutorial in [here](https://hackernoon.com/react-native-for-beginners-fb3095968acf), and I get the following error when trying to run the second app version (v0.1.1).

I'm using expo to create the project, as suggested in the tutorial.
I tried deleting node_modules and re-installing the dependencies, I tried doing the steps suggested in the error.

I googled the error and tried the steps suggested [here](https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/8) (removing `babel-preset-expo` from dependencies and re-installing them), but nothing helped.

Is this a version issue? I see that `Ionicons.ttf` does exist under `node_modules\@expo\vector-icons`, but in a different path, `@expo/vector-icons/website/src/fonts`

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://192.168.1.102:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fyossiv%2Fgit%2Fqr-scanner%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js

Body: {"originModulePath":"/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/App.js",
       "targetModuleName":"@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf",
       "message":"Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf` from `/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/App.js`: Module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf` from `/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/App.js`: Module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf` from `/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/App.js`: Module `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
 at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)
 at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)
 at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:238:485)
 at Object.resolve (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:180:25)
 at dependencies.map.result (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:311:29)
 at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:307:16)
 at /Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:164:33
 at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/yossiv/git/qr-scanner/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:266:307)"} processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:300 access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:37 onChunkComplete
    BundleDownloader.java:224 emitChunk
    MultipartStreamReader.java:76 readAllParts
    MultipartStreamReader.java:154 processMultipartResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:208 access$100
    BundleDownloader.java:37 onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:169 c
    RealCall.java:135 run
    NamedRunnable.java:32 runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133 run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607 run
    Thread.java:761
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to do  `npm install --save @expo/vector-icons`
 and change imports path `@expo/vector-icons/fonts/...` by the new route  `@expo/vector-icons/website/src/fonts/...`  in the files you call that font.

example

```
import IoniconsFont from '@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf';
```

by

```
import IoniconsFont from '@expo/vector-icons/website/src/fonts/Ionicons.ttf';
```

Comment: It worked! thank you
I guess the path of the fonts changed between versions of `@expo/vector-icons `

Answer (score 0):

A conflict may occur due to module installation using the same icon.

`npm install --save @expo/vector-icons`

Comment: @YossiVainshtein  Recreate your project and download the module first from the answers above.

Comment: Download `@expo/vector-icons` and download `native-base`

Comment: What do you mean "download"? can you write ehich commands to use? Thanks

Comment: It is because my English is not good enough. The download I said is to do the install.